# Ways to update one table using another skipping null values

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have table1 and table2 (both have the same columns), I want to insert all records in table2 into table1 if they do not exists in table1, overwise I want to update table1's columns with all non NULL columns of table2.

I didnt manage to find a way to produce one sql that does both things.
As for the first part i manged with INSERT OR IGNORE.
The 2nd part is the problem.

This is what i have:

```
UPDATE main.datas           
SET ot=(
  SELECT ot FROM cards.datas 
  WHERE main.datas.id = cards.datas.id AND cards.datas.ot <> NULL
);
```

problem is, is that the whole (SELECT...) return NULL because of the cards.datas.ot <> NULL part. i tried doing cards.datas.ot IS NOT NULL instead but it just ignores it and sets NULL values as well.

Comment: Don't use = or <> when you want to compare against NULL. Use `column IS NULL` or `column IS NOT NULL`

Comment: As i said, i already did that.

Comment: Are you sure that cards.datas.ot for the same id is not null?

Comment: Yes, ive checked multiple times by setting in one of the records main.datas.ot a number, while setting in the same id on cards.datas.ot as NULL. it replaced the number in main to the NULL in cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the WHERE ... IS NOT NULL condition in the UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE main.datas           
SET ot = (SELECT ot FROM cards.datas WHERE main.datas.id = cards.datas.id)
WHERE (SELECT ot FROM cards.datas WHERE main.datas.id = cards.datas.id) is not null
```

or use coalesce():

```
UPDATE main.datas           
SET ot=coalesce((
  SELECT ot FROM cards.datas 
  WHERE main.datas.id = cards.datas.id AND cards.datas.ot IS NOT NULL
), ot);
```

Comment: Thanks the first one worked, the 2nd didnt. can you explain so i could avoid this in the future?

Comment: The 2nd did not work because I just copied it from your question without changing the <> to IS NOT. I edited. What the code does is: it updates only if it finds NOT NULL value from the table cards.datas. If it is NULL it does not update.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to write this uses `not exists`:

```
UPDATE main.datas md         
    SET ot = (SELECT cd.ot
              FROM cards.datas cd
              WHERE md.id = cd.id AND cd.ot IS NOT NULL
             )
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT cd.ot
                  FROM cards.datas cd
                  WHERE md.id = cd.id AND cd.ot IS NOT NULL
                 );
```

This runs the risk of an error if the first subquery returns more than one row.  For that reason, you might want to include `LIMIT 1` or an aggregation function.